# Multiple Producers and consumers problem in Java (Without BlockingQueue)

Tags: java, concurrency, pthreads

I am refreshing my memory about Java concurrency and I was playing around with the popular producer consumer problem. I have implemented the below code which works correctly if there is a single producer and a single consumer. However, It doesn't function correctly if there are multiple producers/consumers. I can't see why

```
public class ProducerConsumer {

    static Monitor monitor;

    public ProducerConsumer(int maxSize)
    {
        monitor = new Monitor(maxSize);
        new Producer().start();
        new Producer().start();
        new Consumer().start();
        new Consumer().start();
    }

    class Producer extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    monitor.insert();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Consumer extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    monitor.remove();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

     class Monitor {

          int n;
          int maxSize;

         public Monitor(int maxSize)
         {
             n=0;
             this.maxSize = maxSize;
         }

        synchronized void insert() throws InterruptedException 
        {
            if(n==maxSize)
                wait();
            System.out.println("Producer: "+n++);
            if(n==1)
                notifyAll();
        }

        synchronized void remove() throws InterruptedException 
        {
            if(n==0)
                wait();
            System.out.println("Consumer: "+n--);
            if(n==maxSize-1)
                notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProducerConsumer pc = new ProducerConsumer(100);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wait()` should always be used in the following way:

```
while(condition not met) 
    wait();
```

Otherwise some thread can wake up and continue when condition is still not met. There are two possible reasons for this situation:

1. When you call `notifyAll()`, you awake all waiting threads, so that some of them can be too late, when condition is false again (i.e. when limited resource is already exhausted by other threads).
2. There is a possibility of spurious wakeups (i.e. thread wakes up without corresponding `notify`).

If you actually need to wake up only one thread, you can use `notify()` instead of `notifyAll()`. It eliminates the first problem, but still can't protect you from spurious wakeups, so that `while` is still required.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. However, I thought the synchronized method does not allow any thread to enter it if a thread is already in it. What do i misunderstand about this concept that led to this behavior ?

Comment: @3ashmawy: Yes, but when thread calls `wait()` it releases the lock. After subsequent `notifyAll()` awakened threads queue up to acquire the lock again and continue after `wait()`. Obviously, first threads in that queue will change the state and the last ones will find condition not met again.

Comment: Note, be _very_ careful using `notify()` as wakeups can get lost if you don't handle everything just right.